# Lambda timeout config get reset to 1 on deploying using chalice

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, chalice

I am writing a scheduler using [Chalice Event Sources](https://github.com/aws/chalice/blob/master/docs/source/topics/events.rst) (`Cron` class). I've deployed the code and set the lambda timeout settings in AWS console to 8 mins. But whenever I deploy new changes using command `chalice deploy --stage dev` the timeout gets reset to default value i.e. 1min.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the timeout in the chalice config.

Chalice deploys the settings for the Lambda function, so they must be set in the configuration for Lambda.

look in .chalice/config.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "gtf",
  "stages": {
    "dev": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "dev",
      "lambda_functions": {
        "message_queue": { #This is your function name
            "lambda_timeout": 30
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/configfile.html

Comment: If the above code does not work for you. Please follow this link https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1113